# What is the Gigabyte transferred and Gigabyte stored for the hosting in firebase?

Tags: firebase

I have a website using angular but i can't understand the hosting pricing option for Gigabyte stored and Gigabyte transfered.

Is it like every time a user opens my website or click or opens a page in my website i get charged for it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello you can see this link please

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-gb-stored-and-gb-transferred-firebase

**Data storage** = total amount of data in your account on the last day of a month

**Data transfer** = total amount of data uploaded as well as downloaded through your account the whole month

Thx u

Comment: but still cant understand

Comment: Hi, please include the part of data in the link within your answer so your answer still stays meaningful if the link gets corrupt.